# What Was the Extent of the Princes' Authority?

Tags: malchut-royalty, politics-government, parshat-nasso, police-authorities, princes-of-tribes

In [Numbers 7](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0407.htm), we are told about the special offerings the princes of the Tribes brought to the Tabernacle. This is not the only time we hear of this position. Princes are present in [Joshua 9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/e/et/et0609.htm) also, for example.

**What sort of authority did the Princes have?** What could they do, exactly? Where they beholden to some sort of tribe-wide council, just to Moses and the Sanhedrin, or did they have authority even in the face of the national leader and courts?

Please source you answers!

Comment: The details you ask about are whom they were beholden to or whether they could act unilaterally. I think a question one needs to address simultaneously is what they could do: decree social norms? advise _Moshe_? act as figureheads (somewhat akin to the queen in Britain or the president in Israel)? mete punishment? schedule _maamados_ (did those exist in the _mishkan_?)? etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this counts as an answer, but I'll post two commentators:

- **Rashi** (1:16): they were called for all important matters in the camp (administrative duties?)
- **Ibn Ezra:** the nation wouldn't do anything until they [the princes] would call them

I think this suffices to show that they were in fact leaders of some kind: both symbolic (as they would call the people together) and in that they probably oversaw things like the camp's organization - whose tent was where, etc. but weren't necessarily part of Moshe/Yisro's court system